# Need full example on this topic: QtWebKit Bridge

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, webkit

I am new to Qt and currently I am doing some stuff on this topic: http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qtwebkit-bridge.html

What I am trying to do is:

1. create a JS object that maps to a C++ class with many properties and functions.
2. this C++ class could return any JS data types to JS environment.
3. this C++ class could accept any JS data types parameters from JS environment.

But I have no idea how to start, so I am wondering are there any full examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this blogpost: http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2010/11/16/some-webkit-hybrid-stuff/

There are some explanations, and a complete example is linked.